# Inno Setup Cleaning up files with certain extensions after installation

Tags: inno-setup

I've encountered a certain problem with leftovers after installation with inno setup.

I have set `Flags: deleteafterinstall` in `[FILE]` section, and it worked fine untill I added a some code that is renaming destination folder to different name durring installation, and since then Inno Setup is leaving all that files with that flag untouched which looks messy.

As a solution a created this simple batch file that I run in the end of installation via `[CODE]` section.

Clean_Up.bat:

```
del /s /f *.rej
del /s /f *.orig
del /s /f sed*
del /s /f *.patch
del /s /f *.exe
del /s /f *.bat
```

I'm copying this batch that way:

```
[FILE]
Source: "{#CompPath}\BatchFiles\Clean_Up.bat"; DestDir: "{app}\subfolder"; Flags: deleteafterinstall
```

I'm launching it with this:

```
[RUN]
Filename: "{app}\res_mods\Clean_Up.bat"; flags: runhidden;
```

The problem is that this batch is suppose to clean up also .batch files, and the result is that `CleanUp.bat` is also being removed and this is unwanted.

I wanted to solve this by copying it to `{app}` instead of `{app}\subfolder`and edit batch file to this:

```
del /s /f subfolder\*.rej
del /s /f subfolder\*.orig
del /s /f subfolder\sed*
del /s /f subfolder\*.patch
del /s /f subfolder\*.exe
del /s /f subfolder\*.bat
```

However it's giving me error: `The system cannot find the file specified.`

Can someone advise me how to make it work? I think the best way would be to rewrite this batch in pascal code and place in the code section, but I don't know how.

Comment: Why do you rename the folder anyway? Why don't you install files directly yo the `res_mods`?

Comment: Would have to totaly rework how the installer is installing to that folder. We have a situation now where there are three different client versions and I want to support them all. There was no problem with that before, but now I must deal with a new situation so I'm seeking for a easiest and fastes solution for now before I rework it.

Comment: So did my answer help? Or do you need something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you run the batch file, the subfolder is already renamed. So you need to use the new name:

```
del /s /f res_mods\*.rej
del /s /f res_mods\*.orig
...
```

---

Or use the [`WorkingDir` parameter](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=runsection&anchor=WorkingDir) to run the batch file in the subfolder:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\clean_up.bat"; WorkingDir: "{app}\res_mods"; Flags: runhidden;
```

Then you can use the original batch file:

```
del /s /f *.rej
del /s /f *.orig
...
```

---

Also you can avoid use of the batch file by directly executing the `del` command directly in the `[Run]` section:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "/C del /s /f *.rej"; WorkingDir: "{app}\res_mods"; \
    Flags: runhidden
Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "/C del /s /f *.orig"; WorkingDir: "{app}\res_mods"; \
    Flags: runhidden
...
```

---

*Though personally, as you rename the folder in `[Code]` section, I'd remove the files in code too. For a consistency.*

Comment: I found out that `[RUN]` section is too soon for this batch, I moved its execution to the `[CODE]` section.

I have to place it in `CurStep=ssDone`

How would `del /s /f res_mods\*.rej` look like in the code instead of batch?

Comment: `Exec(ExpandConstant('{cmd}'), '/c del ...', ...);` Check documentation of the `Exec` function.